# firestore in angular 7 how to get document id

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to add document id in each of mServiceListObj

```
  this.firestore.collection('service').snapshotChanges().take(1).subscribe(data => {
      this.mServiceListObj = data.map(e => {
        return {

          ...e.payload.doc.data()
        } as Item;

      });

    });
```

In the above code, it is fetching data but without document id.
How to add document id in that object

```
export class Item {
  id: String;
  cat: String;
  img: String;
  title: String;
  actiontitle: String;
  subt1: String = "milla";
  subt2: String;
  mServiceIncluded: Array<ServiceIncluded> = [];//=ServiceIncluded();
  mServiceDetails: Array<ServiceDetail> = [];//ServiceDetail();
  actionlist: Array<ActionModel> = [];
  constructor() {

  }
  setBaseDate(title): Item {
    this.title = title;
    return this;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.payload.doc.id` will give you the id of the document.

So the mapping wil be like this:

```
return {
   ...e.payload.doc.data(),
   id: e.payload.doc.id
} as Item;
```

Comment: error TS2352: Conversion of type '{ id: string; }' to type 'Item' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Property 'cat' is missing in type '{ id: string; }'.

Comment: The document id type is string. So you should change to type of id property in your model to string.

Comment: You last voted on this answer 11 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.